# Batch Creating QR Codes for Labels

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I am trying to create a web page on which I can batch create QR codes (they are eventually going to be printed on stickers and used as labels.) I would like to be able to create the amount of QR codes specified by the user of the page under the "Amount of labels" input field. For example, they select "five" and click the Generate button and it generates five QR codes. The code that I have written so far only generates one QR code, and I am unsure about how to write the code necessary for it to generate the amount of codes specified by the user on the webpage. If anyone has any suggestions, I would be very thankful. Please let me know if you require further information. Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>QR code generator</title>
<style>
  body { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
  section {
    margin: 50px auto;
    max-width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  textarea {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  #size { max-width: 64px; }
  label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: left;
  .container {
  width: 500px;
  clear: both;
}

.container input {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
}
}​
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
  <h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
  <p>Enter a URL or some text bellow and hit the Generate button (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)!</p>
  <textarea id="textarea" autofocus></textarea>
  <div class="block">
  <label for="size">Size (px):</label>
  <input align="left" id="size" type="number" value="150" min="50" max="500" step="50">
  <label for="amount">Amount of Labels:</label>
  <input align="left" id="amount" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="20" step="1">
  <button onclick="genQRcode()">Generate</button>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="display: none;">
    <p><img id="qrcode" src="" /></p>
    <label for="qrcode-url">QR Code URL:</label>
    <input id="qrcode-url" type="text" onclick="this.select()">
  </div>
</section>
<script>
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
    content = document.getElementById("content");

  function genQRcode() {
    var data = encodeURIComponent(textarea.value),
      size = document.getElementById("size").value,
      chart = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=" + size + "x" + size + "&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0&chl=" + data;
    if (data === "") {
      alert("Please enter valid data!");
      textarea.focus();
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "";
      document.getElementById("qrcode").src = chart;
      document.getElementById("qrcode-url").value = chart;
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
      genQRcode();
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, you only have one element which holds a QR code. I expect at the very least you'll need one of those for each QR code to generate. So, some research into how to create HTML elements is probably a good first step. I would suggest placing the code that creates those HTML elements in your `getQRCode`. Then you'd just need a loop to call that function the number of times necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I will do some research. @HereticMonkey

Comment: I am still kind of lost, to be honest.

Comment: Surely you're going to need separate input fields for the data that will be contained within each generated QR code, otherwise they'll all be the same?

Comment: Well, eventually it's going to be one URL that will be concatenated with other information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in this example, an html template is used to create the display for the qr code...

```
<script id="template-qr-code" type="text/html">
  <p><img id="qrcode" src="{{src}}" /></p>
  <label for="qrcode-url-{{i}}">QR Code URL:</label>
  <input id="qrcode-url-{{i}}" type="text" onclick="this.select()" value="{{src}}" />
</script>
```

then a `for` loop, based on the amount of qr codes to create,
the same url is used for all the qr codes...

```
for (var i = 0; i < amount.value; i++) {
  var qrSrc = qrTemplate.innerHTML;
  qrSrc = qrSrc.replace(new RegExp('{{src}}', 'g'), chart);
  qrSrc = qrSrc.replace(new RegExp('{{i}}', 'g'), i);
  content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', qrSrc);
}
```

see following working snippet...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>QR code generator</title>
<style>
body { font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
section {
  margin: 50px auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  text-align: center;
}
textarea {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#size { max-width: 64px; }
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 140px;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<section>
  <h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
  <p>Enter a URL or some text bellow and hit the Generate button (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)!</p>
  <textarea id="textarea" autofocus></textarea>
  <div class="block">
    <label for="size">Size (px):</label>
    <input align="left" id="size" type="number" value="150" min="50" max="500" step="50">
    <label for="amount">Amount of Labels:</label>
    <input align="left" id="amount" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="20" step="1">
    <button id="genQRcode">Generate</button>
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="display: none;"></div>
</section>
<script id="template-qr-code" type="text/html">
  <p><img id="qrcode" src="{{src}}" /></p>
  <label for="qrcode-url-{{i}}">QR Code URL:</label>
  <input id="qrcode-url-{{i}}" type="text" onclick="this.select()" value="{{src}}" />
</script>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
    content = document.getElementById("content"),
    amount = document.getElementById("amount"),
    qrTemplate = document.getElementById('template-qr-code');

  function genQRcode() {
    var data = encodeURIComponent(textarea.value),
      size = document.getElementById("size").value,
      chart = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=" + size + "x" + size + "&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0&chl=" + data;
    if (data === "") {
      alert("Please enter valid data!");
      textarea.focus();
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < amount.value; i++) {
        var qrSrc = qrTemplate.innerHTML;
        qrSrc = qrSrc.replace(new RegExp('{{src}}', 'g'), chart);
        qrSrc = qrSrc.replace(new RegExp('{{i}}', 'g'), i);
        content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', qrSrc);
      }
      content.style.display = "";
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("genQRcode").addEventListener("click", genQRcode);

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
      genQRcode();
    }
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really can not thank you enough for this. Wow. Thank you so much! Very helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much!